# Always hide paper-drawer-panel without using responsive-width="9999px"

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0

How can I set my `paper-drawer-panel` to always be hidden, in other words, what's the equivalent of setting `responsive-width="99999px"`? I can use that approach but it seems fairly ugly since I always want it to be hidden (unless one press a button to open it). Is there some property that I'm missing? Kinda like `always-hide="true"`? Or must I use the responsive-width property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`forceNarrow`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel) (`force-narrow` when written as *attribute* in html).

> If true, ignore responsiveWidth setting and force the narrow layout.

Comment: Ahh, I'm so stupid. I saw it in the docs, but when I read it I somehow in my mind took it as the reverse scenario (always show them). Anyway, it worked, thank you!